# eluceo/ical how to remove an event

Tags: php, icalendar

I'm using eluceo/ical to add events from an app to my calendar. This is working great and I have successfully added multiple events to my calendar however if i remove an event from the app it is retained by the calendar. How can i remove the event?

Consider the following function that creates the calendar.

```
    public function createUserCalendar(): Component
    {
        // Get the shortname of the user
        $boom = explode( ' ', $this->name );
        $shortName = $boom[0];

        $events = [];
        $pending = $this->calendarPending()->get();

        foreach ( $pending as $day ) {
            $eventUid = 'ecl-' . $day->user_id . '-' . $day->id;
            $uniqueIdentifier = new UniqueIdentifier($eventUid);

            if ( $day->half_days === 1 ) {
                $summary = $shortName . ' Half day ' . $day->period;
            } else {
                $summary = $shortName . ' Full day';
            }
            $event = new Event( $uniqueIdentifier );

            $firstDay = new Date(\DateTimeImmutable::createFromFormat( 'Y-m-d', $day->date ));
            $lastDay = new Date(\DateTimeImmutable::createFromFormat( 'Y-m-d', $day->date));

            $occurrence = new MultiDay($firstDay, $lastDay);

            $event->setSummary( $summary )
                ->setStatus( EventStatus::CONFIRMED())
                ->setDescription( $day->description )
                ->setOccurrence( $occurrence );

            $events[] = $event;
        }

        $cancelled = $this->calendarCancelled()->get();

        foreach ( $cancelled as $day ) {
            $eventUid = 'ecl-' . $day->user_id . '-' . $day->id;
            $uniqueIdentifier = new UniqueIdentifier($eventUid);

            $event = new Event( $uniqueIdentifier );
            $firstDay = new Date(\DateTimeImmutable::createFromFormat( 'Y-m-d', $day->date ));
            $lastDay = new Date(\DateTimeImmutable::createFromFormat( 'Y-m-d', $day->date));

            $occurrence = new MultiDay($firstDay, $lastDay);

            $event->setOccurrence( $occurrence )->setStatus( EventStatus::CANCELLED());

            $events[] = $event;
        }

        // 2. Create Calendar domain entity
        $calendar = new Calendar( $events );

        // 3. Transform domain entity into an iCalendar component
        return (new CalendarFactory())->createCalendar( $calendar );
    }
```

If I run this and add to the calendar I see all the days added correct as expected. If I then cancel an event and resubmit the calendar it still shows the event. So how do I remove it from my calendar and/or cancel this event?

thanks

*** EDIT ***

Here is a sample of what is in my generated ics file which includes a cancelled event. As mentioned in a comment below I'm using Laravel9 and php8.1 if that helps and the docs for eluceo/ical can be found on https://ical.poerschke.nrw/docs

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//eluceo/ical//2.0/EN
VERSION:2.0
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:ecl-77-25
DTSTAMP:20230222T153729Z
SUMMARY:Room 8 booking
DESCRIPTION:Booking room 8
DTSTART:20230224
DTEND:20230225
STATUS:CONFIRMED
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:ecl-77-7
DTSTAMP:20230222T153729Z
DTSTART:20230315
DTEND:20230316
STATUS:CANCELLED
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Comment: It's a bit unclear, but i assume the event data comes from `$this->calendarPending()->get()`? Where is that data coming from in the end - i.e. where is it being stored? You'd need to remove the event from that source, I would think. Also what is "eluceo/ical"? Please provide some sort of explanation / reference for what that is and how it's relevant.

Comment: That is a call to the database table of the events entered onto the app. It is then looped over for each day. This aspect is working as is the collection of cancelled events. The ical is created and has all the expected data. I perhaps should have stated that I'm using Laravel9 and php8.1

Comment: Ok. So if you want to remove an event, you will need to delete it from the database by the sound of it. The iCal file just contains whatever is in the database when you generate it.

Comment: the library you are using just generates the iCal files. It has nothing to do in how to store them in a db or in how to handle the replies from the iCal.

Comment: If I remove it then nothing is sent to the calendar and so it stays there. Which I think is expected behaviour as if i was to add a single event then it would remove everything in my calendar right? I've edited my question. I have previously added the event with the uid of ecl-77-7 (on the 15th March) but setting it as cancelled does nothing.

Comment: @LelioFaieta My issue is not the app but it is how to dynamically remove an event from a calendar using an ics file. Say I have added 100 events and 20 are cancelled how can I generate an ics file which will remove these cancelled entries? I assume I do not need to manually go into the calendar and delete each one right?

Comment: You'd need to delete it from the database and then make the calendar refresh its data by requesting a new ics file. Unless whatever calendar component you're using provides a way to directly delete from the calendar at the same time you remove it from the database, removing the need for a full refresh.

Comment: `how can I generate an ics file which will remove these cancelled entries`...by ensuring the cancelled entries are not present in the data source the ics file is generated from. That could be achieved, as I said, by causing the entry to be deleted from the database when the user removes it from the calendar via the app.

Comment: where is your datastore? are they events saved in a database?
 Can you confirm they are removed from the database when you cancel?

Comment: My database table for the events has a cancelled flag. If I just get the events that are not cancelled and submit them without the cancelled events then it doesn't remove the events in the calendar. This makes sense as if i say added just one event then it shouldn't remove everything else in the calendar right?

Comment: @EmekaMbah It is a table of the event data ie the uid, day, the summary, the description and a cancelled field. The function above then builds the events and adds the array of events to the calendar.

Comment: Ok. So your code from `$cancelled = $this->calendarCancelled()->get();` onwards seems to be explicitly searching for cancelled events in the database and adding them to the ics file. If you don't want that, maybe remove that bit of code. Either that, or reprogram the component which receives the ics file, and tell it to ignore events with STATUS:CANCELLED in them

Comment: So my first draft of the code submitted above was a single block containing only items that get added. The entries that I wanted removed remain in the calendar after this import. I then checked the documentation and seen the cancelled thing so i added a block containing events to remove. I'll go back a few steps and try again.

Comment: ok so i commented out the cancelled section and created an ics with 3 events in it. I imported it into a different accout this time. The events got instantly added. I then created a new ics which had one of the events removed and I imported this. The day not in the second file stayed on the calendar.

Comment: This sounds like an something which needs solving within the calendar component in the app then, but obviously not knowing anything about that I can't advise whether that's the intended behaviour in that scenario, or a bug, nor what to do about it. But with the functionality as you've currently described it, it seems that removing an event will need to be a two-step process: 1) remove the event from the calendar on the app, and then 2) mark the event as cancelled in the database. So you'll need to build functionality in your app which triggers both of those steps at once, I think.

Comment: So not possible. You are suggesting almost the exact opposite of my process and would be a massive refactoring of the app. I notice that there are apps that claim to be able to do this (https://www.gcaltoolkit.com) so not sure why it isn't documented and how I would do it.

Comment: How would that be the opposite of your process? Surely it's just a missing piece? What exactly _is_ the process you've implemented, then? All you seem to have right now is the ability to load things into the calendar from the database (via PHP). Surely at the point a user deletes something from the calendar in your app, you can trigger a call back to the PHP to also delete it from the database. That would be a pretty standard solution.

Comment: but deleting it from the app isn't the issue. That is already being handled (We actually cancel so it can reverted if needed). My problem is that it isn't automatically deleted from the google calendar I export to. It seems you are saying that we should be polling the calendar but this is restricted so only one user can manually edit it. I expected I could do this so a booking is made in the app and this is sent to the calendar but this only seems to work if I add to the calendar and if something is removed it remains on the calendar due to no apparent way to delete it via the import

Comment: `the google calendar I export to`...what google calendar? You've never mentioned this before. The architecture you described appeared to involve the app on the phone reading the ICS file which was generated from PHP, and having its own local store of events. There was no mention of any other components. How and when does exporting to a google calendar happen? And how does that relate to everything else we've been talking about? Does the google calendar also read from your ICS file, or something?

Comment: Hi AdDyson, the calendar used is a shared calendar used by some users to see what rooms are booked and these users might not have access to the booking app itself. We've not synced anything yet. Only solution that appears to be the case is to remove the entire calendar and add a new copy by downloading the ics unlinking/deleting it from the calendar and reimporting it again. This would of course remove all bookings while this process happens. How this relates is I was asking how can i programmatically remove an event from a google calendar. I guess I cant right?

Comment: Yes you can, Google Calendar has an API you can call

Comment: ah thanks. A quick google and i found https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/delete